# Error with compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Below is my build.graddle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

}
```

Not exactly sure what the problem is, but i've look up similar post but my issue still persist.

something tells the issue has to do with the following line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

more elaborated

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META- INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.0.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Gradle console output, not just those two lines.

Comment: what about `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.0.0'` too old

Comment: when bringing it down to 7.3.0 i receive around 20 errors Error:(7, 30) error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity
Error:(40, 35) error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity
Error:(83, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(85, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(87, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(94, 46) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(108, 46) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(111, 37) error: cannot find symbol method getResources()

...

Comment: I am not sure but I read some time ago that adding old versions will throw an error. The latest release is 8.4 from December 2015, maybe You can try this one...

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` **Clean-Rebuild-sync**

Answer (score 2):

You should try with latest version

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Sync** Your Project .